# Having trouble returning a User object with Django

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to use Django's authentication system to login in a user. But I can't figure out how to create a `User` object, I've just been playing around with it so far:

```
def sign_in(request):

    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save()
        post.save()
        username = request.POST.get(post.question_text)
        password = request.POST.get(post.id_text)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponse('hi')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('bye')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'checkin/sign_in_new.html', {'form': form})
```

The program keeps returning `bye`. I'm not sure what I need to put as the parameters for `request.POST.get()`, the Django docs uses 'username' and 'password' respectively. Do I need to write code to create the user first? I created one in the Django API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, I just need to create the `user` in my code first. I just added `user = User.objects.create_user('charlie', 'charlesdsmith25@gmail.com', 'smith')` so now it's:

```
def sign_in(request):
    #we need to handle all the data that was just typed, we'll add a condition for that
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save()
        post.save()
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = User.objects.create_user('charlie', 'charlesdsmith25@gmail.com', 'smith')
        auth = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponse('hi')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('bye')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'checkin/sign_in_new.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

The user doesn't exist. Go to admin and create one first. And yes user needs to be created before you attempt to sign in.

Comment: But how would someone sign up for a new account for example?

Comment: I can't explain in a statement, but can you mind reading this http://blog.narenarya.in/right-way-django-authentication.html

Comment: I've actually been to that site lol. I don't think it shows me how to create a user, it just shows how to authenticate an already existing user

Comment: I figured it out and added an answer with the updated code, I just needed to add one line that created the user first